# Gracefully exit from a PowerShell background wait-event loop on Linux

Tags: linux, powershell

I have a PowerShell script I am kicking off in the background on Linux.
`> ./test_wait.ps1 &`

I am trying to exit the background process so that the finally block is executed. But none of the signals (or Stop-Process) works. The finally block is always skipped. If I start it in the foreground and use Ctrl-C then everything works. But when it is a background process it doesn't respond to SIGINT, and other signals just cause it to immediately exit. Am I missing something? Or am I going to have approach this another way?

```
#!/usr/bin/pwsh
$Start_Time = (Get-date).second
$n = 1
Try
{
        While($true) {
                $n ++
                Wait-Event  1
        }
}
Finally
{
        $End_Time = (Get-date).second
        $Time_Diff = $End_Time - $Start_Time
        "Total time in seconds $Time_Diff" > out.log
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong here but you're never showing us your `Register-ObjectEvent`. I think, unless the `Action` of your objectEvent can `break` the `while($true){...}` loop (which I'm not sure if it's possible, I rarely use these cmdlets), then this loop will go indefinitely.

Comment: You're right, I am not in this example. I have simplified the actual script I am running down to the example just to filter out extraneous noise. My understanding is the Wait-Event without qualifiers will wait for the next event of any kind. When run in the foreground the example will break the loop and run the finally code when Ctrl-c is pressed.